# Where to store decrypted files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I am encrypting downloaded files and saving them locally in app's documents directory.

To read them you must decrypt those file and store some where temporarily.

*My concerns are:*

1.if I store them in doc directory for time they are being used, for that time window one can get those files using tools like iExplorer.

2.My idea is to store them in memory for the time they are being used and flush the vault after use.
**This option is good for small files but for large files say 50 MB or video of 100 MB, I am afraid that app will receive memory warning in result will terminate abruptly.**

I want to know the best approach for doing this.

Comment: any way to split up the file into chunks so you can read one encrypted chunk into memory, and there decrypt it?

Comment: this might be an option but this would not be an easy job and for certain files which stores meta data in their footer or while clicking a link on a pdf page, this would not help. You need to study file structure of each file type and the mechanism of reading them.

Comment: There is no perfect solution to this problem but decrypting on the fly is the safest.  There are ways to decrypt video on the fly as it's displayed, eg (though I don't understand them well enough to explain it).

Answer (score 2):

There is **no perfect security storing local files in a safe way**. If a person has full access to the device, he can always find a way to decrypt the files, as long as your application is able to decrypt it.

The only question is: **How much effort is necessary to decrypt the files?**

If your only concern is that a person may use iExplorer to copy and open these files, a simple local symmetric encryption will do the trick.

Just **embed a random symmetric key** in your application and encrypt the data block by block while you download it.

You can use the comfortable "Security Transforms" framework to do the symmetric encryption. There are some good examples in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecTransformPG/EncryptionandDecryption/EncryptionandDecryption.html).

When you load the files, you can use the same key to decrypt them while you load them from the file system.

Just to make things clear: **This is not a perfect protection** of the files. But to decrypt the files, one has access to your app binary. Analyse this binary in a debugger and searching for the decryption part to extract your symmetric key. This is a lot effort necessary just to decrypt the files.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt them, obfuscate them with a toy algorithm (e. g. XOR with a constant block), and store them in documents. When needed, load and decrypt.

Since the problem has no solution in theory (a determined enough attacker can read your process memory after all), it's as good a solution as any.

Comment: XORing data with "a constant block" is not secure at all for most file formats.

Comment: Nothing is secure is the app is capable of decrypting the files. It's more like obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Split your files into smaller sizes before saving them, then decrypt on load.

Later edit: I noticed this is mentioned in the comments. I agree splitting files isn't the easiest thing in the world, but presumably you'll only need this for video. About 100MB is a lot of text or audio. If your PDF weights as much,  it's probably scanned text, and you can change it into a series if images.

And yes, splitting better be done server-side, don't want the user waste battery in video processing.

Comment: i am not sure whether this can be done using iOS sdk because when media file is given to AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController, first they process whole file to know about its metadata. With chunks of bytes how will I come to know that particular chunk is needed and decrypt in between.

Comment: This won't be trivial, but this is something your server is better suited to do: Split the file beforhand and provide you information about chunk offsets.